# Loading product content via AJAX in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, opencart

Using OpenCart how would I show a categories products as content loaded via AJAX from a MySQL database? This content would be then shown inside a `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.org) and use their AJAX support. Put an `onclick` handler on each category link, which calls a function that fetches the category data from the server. It can be raw html, which you then replace the contents of that  with.

The server-side script would generate JUST the html necessary to display the product info. Since you'll be inserting it into a div inside an existent page, there's no need for headers/footers, just the core product data.